# How to set a gradient to the left/right/top of a QFrame

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets, qgradient

I have a QFrame used in a main window. The background color requirement for this QFrame is:

> Background
> Color 69/69/69
> Top-outline 1px; 90/90/90
> Right-outline 1px; 49/49/49
> Shadow inside 16px; color 0/0/0;
> opacitity 15%

and to have a line on top of this frame:

> Line
> Size 1px
> Color 49/49/49

Here, I am unable to give the shadow effect for the background.  The style sheet used is:

```css
border-right: 1px solid #313131;
border-top: 1px solid #313131;
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #5A5A5A, 
    stop: 0.05 #5A5A5A, 
    stop:0.06 rgb(0,0,0,38.5), 
    stop:0.43 rgb(0,0,0,38.5), 
    stop:0.44 #454545);
```

Using this, I can get the shadow effect only for the top side, and I want to get the same for the right end of this frame.

[image: qframe image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use QRadialGradient instead.

See [Qt Style Sheets Reference — List of Properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties)

Something like this should give you a result similar to what you're trying to do:

```css
background: qradialgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius: 2.5,
                fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 white, stop:1 black);
```

You can take a look at [QRadialGradient Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qradialgradient.html), or just play a bit with the values to achieve what you need.